# Detect when UIView changes size during animation for shadow to move

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, shadow

In a `UIView` subclass, I have the following property override for `override var bounds: CGRect`:

```
@IBDesignable
class GEView: UIView {

    private var shadowView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            guard let superview = superview else { return }
            guard let shadowView = self.shadowView else { return }

            // Add the shadow to the superview, as the shadow cannot
            // also allow rounded corners simultaneously
            superview.addSubview(shadowView)
            shadowView.layer.zPosition = layer.zPosition - 1
            shadowView.edges(to: self)
        }
    }

    // CALLED WHEN SETTING @IBInspectable PROPERTIES
    /// Creates a shadow if one has not yet been created.
    private func createShadowIfNeeded() {
        guard shadowView == nil else { return }

        shadowView = UIView()

        shadowView?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:    bounds,
                                                    cornerRadius:   cornerRadius).cgPath
        shadowView?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    }


    // THE PROPERTY TO ATTEMPT THE SHADOW MOVING
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            shadowView?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:    bounds,
                                                        cornerRadius:   cornerRadius).cgPath
        }
    }
}
```

The attempt was to re-draw the shadow many times as the bounds change when the view constraints are animated (leading to the view changing size).

However, the bounds change instantly, as the animation is just visual. Is there a way I can get this shadow to follow the view as it animates? It would be better if this can be in the `UIView` subclass instead of the animation block, which is `UIView.animate`.

Here is what the problem looks like:

[image: Moving view gif]

I want the shadow to follow along whilst the view moves. At the end of the gif, the shadow position and view position are correct, because the override ignores animations and pretends it has already animated.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the `shadow` in `layoutSubviews()` of `CustomView`, i.e.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        let oldPath = self.layer.shadowPath
        let newPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 0.0).cgPath
        if oldPath != nil {
            let shadowPathAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowPath")
            shadowPathAnimation.fromValue = oldPath
            shadowPathAnimation.toValue = newPath
            self.layer.add(shadowPathAnimation, forKey: "shadowAnimation")
            self.layer.shadowPath = newPath
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
            self.trailingConstraint.constant = 200.0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` not trigger from many other views as well though?

Comment: @George_E Why not?

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` will definitely be triggered from elsewhere. You can keep a check of if you've set the shadow details already. This is just an example which can be configured as per your requirements.

Comment: This is how you animate the constrains on a view.

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple views for which the shadow needs to be updated. It would be best to do this within my `UIView` subclass as well

Comment: In that case, update the `shadow` in `layoutSubviews()` of `CustomView`. Updated the code for that.

Comment: No, it's still not being called _as_ the view animates.

Comment: In case you are using `shadowPath`, you need to animate it using `CABasicAnimation`. Updated the code.

Comment: Oh my, that actually worked after some tweaking and learning about `CABasicAnimation`!

Comment: Just a question, how can I add options to the animation, like the rate? (e.g. `curveEaseOut`)

Comment: Ah got it, don't worry. Went through all properties and found out to do `shadowPathAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)` 